# Using Javascript/JQuery to Set Rails `hidden_field_tag` Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use javascript or jquery to make my app recognize whichever `div` has a class of `active` as the value for a `hidden_field_tag` in my erb `form_for`.  So far I have the following structure set up and working:

```
<div id="q1" class="row gen-quest-div">
    <h1>How long do you have?</h1>
    <div class="row answers">
      <div id="q1-15" class="answer q1-answer col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <%= image_tag 'min-15.jpg', alt: "Put 15 minutes on the clock!" %>
        <p>15 Minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div id="q1-30" class="answer q1-answer col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <%= image_tag 'min-30.jpg', alt: "Put 30 minutes on the clock!" %>
        <p>30 Minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div id="q1-45" class="answer q1-answer col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <%= image_tag 'min-45.jpg', alt: "Put 45 minutes on the clock!" %>
        <p>45 Minutes</p>
      </div>
      <div id="q1-60" class="answer q1-answer col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
        <%= image_tag 'min-60.jpg', alt: "Put 60 minutes on the clock!" %>
        <p>60 Minutes</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- answers row -->
  </div> <!-- question div -->

<div class="btn-primary" id="pre-submit">Pre Submit</div>

<script>
// Selection handling
  $( document ).ready(function() {
      $('.q1-answer').on('click', function() {
        $('.q1-answer').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
      $('.q2-answer').on('click', function() {
        $('.q2-answer').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
      $('.q3-answer').on('click', function() {
        $('.q3-answer').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
      });
  });

  // Form handling
  $('#pre-submit').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#q1-15').hasClass('active')) {
        console.log("So far this works.");  // <<<<THIS LINE
      }
  }); 
</script>
```

This successfully selects a `div` by marking it `.active` when it is clicked and prints the `console.log` statement when the answer is selected (just for testing purposes...).  Now the hard part is what to replace the marked line with to make the form recognize the answer.  I have my form structured like this:

```
  <%= form_for @generator do |f| %>
      <div id="q1-form-field">
        <%= hidden_field_tag :time, id: "q1-hf" %>
      </div>
      ...
      <div class="text-center">
        <h3><%= f.submit "Submit" %></h3>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

When no action is taken, the hidden field translates to `<input type="hidden" name="time" id="time" value="{:id=>&quot;q1-hf&quot;}">` in html, which may or may not be a problem.

And have tried several ways to replace the `console.log` statement in the javascript and assign a value to the hidden field based on which `div` is `.active`.

First, `document.getElementById("q1-hf").value = 1;` which receives a console error saying `new:200 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Alternatively, `$('#q1-hf').val(1);` generates no console errors, but also does not change the `hidden_field_tag` value.

Can anyone help me get this working?  I'm open to other structures that accomplish the same goal, but I have looked at other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965503/change-value-of-hidden-field-tag-with-js-prototype-rails-3) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597444/setting-a-form-variable-value-before-submitting) that seem to say this should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= hidden_field_tag :time, id: "q1-hf" %>`

This code is making a hidden input with `id="time"`, so you should select it by `document.getElementById("time")`

---

If you want the id to be "q1-hf", then you should change it to
`<%= hidden_field_tag 'q1-hf' %>`

It will be rendered as `<input name="q1-hf" id="q1-hf" type="hidden">` and you can access it the way you described in your question.

Comment: Ahhh!  Thank you!  I changed the `id` to `time` and it worked perfectly.